# "Auto-correct" argument in Tcsh?

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

Is there anyway to program something like this in Tcsh where an argument gets changed when you press tab. 
Similar as to how on iOS/Android it auto completes "omw" to "On My Way!"

*Note: █ is the Text cursor position*

```
> script.py imgPath█
```

* *[ Press Tab ]* *

```
> script.py this/example/file/path/LONG_IMAGE_NAME_█
```

---

Then from there since I have the full path I can do the normal file name auto completion using tab. For example if I have a file called `LONG_IMAGE_NAME_SCREENSHOT_635.jpg` I can add `S` at the end of the agrument and hit tab like normal:

```
> script.py this/example/file/path/LONG_IMAGE_NAME_S█
```

* *[ Press Tab ]* *

```
> script.py this/example/file/path/LONG_IMAGE_NAME_SCREENSHOT_635.jpg█
```

File link won't work for this because it doesn't add the start of the filename, alias also doesn't work because of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

From `tcsh(1)`:

```
       > set local = /usr/local
       > ls $lo[tab]
       > ls $local/[^D]
       bin/ etc/ lib/ man/ src/
       > ls $local/

   Note  that  variables  can also be expanded explicitly with the expand-
   variables editor command.
```

So as the example shows you can set an `imgPath` variable.

The `expand-variables` is mapped to `^X$` by default (press `^X`, then `$`), and will expand the `$imgPath` to whatever value it holds.

As far as I know, there isn't a way to expand `$imgPath` on tab in tcsh.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of a shortcut that can auto expand the variable!